# Combbox action listener to show and hide an image

Tags: java

I've created a combobox with two options: Hide and Show inside a JPanel. I want to know how I can write an action listener, so when I select "Show" from the drop-down, a picture appears next to the combobox, and hides it when "Hide" is select. Many thanks in advance. 
Following is what I've got so far.

```
myPanel = new javax.swing.JPanel();
myLabel = new javax.swing.JLabel();
myComboBox = new javax.swing.JComboBox();

setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

myLabel.setText("myLabel:");

myComboBox.setModel(new javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel(new String[] { "Hide", "Show" }));

javax.swing.GroupLayout myPanelLayout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(myPanel);
myPanel.setLayout(myPanelLayout);
myPanelLayout.setHorizontalGroup(
    myPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(myPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
.addGap(28, 28, 28)
.addComponent(myLabel)
.addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED)
.addComponent(myComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
.addGap(237, 237, 237))
);
myPanelLayout.setVerticalGroup(
    myPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
    .addGroup(myPanelLayout.createSequentialGroup()
.addGap(44, 44, 44)
.addGroup(myPanelLayout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
    .addComponent(myLabel)
    .addComponent(myComboBox, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
.addContainerGap(36, Short.MAX_VALUE))
);
```

Comment: I gave you a link to the tutorial for a reason. Read the tutorial and follow the example code given there. Yes its a little more work because you can't just copy the spoon fed code, but you learn more and you don't even need to create any custom classes for painting the image.

Comment: The was i did it is the professional way to do it and he chose my answer because i took the time to write him nice clean code that was easy to read.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so i think i understand what you wanted to do so i threw some code together in my eclipse, i hope this helps you in some way!

```
package com.detter.john;

import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.*;
import javax.imageio.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public final class ComboBoxExample extends JFrame implements ActionListener
{
    public ComboBoxExample()
    {
        super("Combo Box Example");
        setLayout(null);
        panel = new JPanel();

        box = new JComboBox(options);
        box.addActionListener(this);

        panel.add(box);
        panel.setSize(100,100);
        panel.setLocation(0,0);
        panel.setVisible(true);

        imagePanel = new ImagePanel();
        add(panel);
        add(imagePanel);

        setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
        setLocation(X,Y);
        setResizable(false);
        setVisible(true);
    }

    public class ImagePanel extends JPanel
    {
        public ImagePanel()
        {
            try
            {
                showing = true;
                image = ImageIO.read(new File("..\\Combobox action listener to show" +
                    " and hide an image\\Images\\SampleImage.PNG"));
            }catch(Exception e){e.printStackTrace();}

            setSize(WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            setLocation(X,Y);
            setVisible(true);
        }

        public void showImage()
        {
            showing = true;
            repaint();
        }

        public void hideImage()
        {
            showing = false;
            repaint();
        }

        public void paint(Graphics g)
        {
            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D)g;
            g2.clearRect(0,0,WIDTH,HEIGHT);
            if(showing)
                g2.drawImage(image,0,0,null);
        }

        private boolean showing;
        private BufferedImage image;

        private static final int WIDTH = 100;
        private static final int HEIGHT = 100;
        private static final int X = 100;
        private static final int Y = 0;
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        if(e.getSource()==box)
        {
            switch(box.getSelectedIndex())
            {
                case SHOW:
                    imagePanel.showImage();
                break;
                case HIDE:
                imagePanel.hideImage();
                break;
            }
        }
   }

    private JPanel panel;
    private ImagePanel imagePanel;
    private JComboBox box;
    private String options[] = {"show","hide"};

    private static final int SHOW = 0;
    private static final int HIDE = 1;

    private static final int X = 0;
    private static final int Y = 0;
    private static final int WIDTH = 206;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 132;

    public static void main(String args[]){new ComboBoxExample();}
}
```

Comment: No problem, i hope it helped!

Comment: Well thats how ive been programming for 10 years and thats just the way i do it, i use the null layout to disable layout manager so i can put the panels wherever i want, i override paint so that i can paint the image everytime repaint() is called, im sure u have your own ways of doing things but thats how i do it.

Comment: @John Detter for Swing JComponents is there paintComponent(s), for Awt and for delegate BasicXxxUI is here paint(), output to the GUI is unexpected, don't mix that please ..., @camickr +1 for simple & clear reasons

Comment: @John Detter, as I said it will work and it may be the way you do it, but the forum to for promoting more standard usage of the API. We spend much of our time answering questions in the forum becuae people learn the wrong approach and don't know any different. Don't reinvent the wheel. JLabels can display images. If you do need to do custom painting, when you override the paintComponent() method, not paint(). Layout manager do take a little more time to understand then using a null layout but the benefits far outweight the negatives and will save time in the long run.

Comment: Well thats the way i would do it, you're telling me whenever you need to display images you should use a JLabel? I wouldnt, with complex games with a lot of animations the way i did it would be best, make a new class that extends JPanel and override paint() so that you can manually update the graphics. I can see where you are coming from if it were somthing small like this but, in the long run i think my approach is better.

Answer (score 0):

Read the JComboBox API and follow the link to the section in the Swing tutorial on 'How to Use Combo Boxes". It has an example of selecting from a list of pictures. I'm sure you can modify it to do what you want.

If you need more help then post your [SSCCE](http://sscce.org) that demonstrates the problem.